# jQuery UI Dialog Auto-Close using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, settimeout

I'm trying to have my dialog auto-close three seconds after opening. I've tried the following methods:

```
setTimeout($("#mydialog").dialog('close'), 3000);
```

Here it is in context:

```
$("#acknowledged-dialog").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
});

setTimeout($("#acknowledged-dialog").dialog('close'), 3000);
```

But with this method, it doesn't even show! I'm guessing the the close method is getting called immediately after it gets shown on the page. The log shows no errors.

I've also tried binding to the dialogopen event:

```
$("#acknowledged-dialog").bind('dialogopen', function(event, ui) {
    setTimeout($(this).dialog('close'), 3000);
});
$("#acknowledged-dialog").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
});
```

The dialog shows, but does not auto-close. No error in the logs here either.

Am I not able to use 'this' in the argument for $ in setTimeout?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

setTimeout is calling on the the return value of $("#mydialog").dialog("close") after 3 seconds.  you want to throw the whole thing as a string, and it should work just fine.  Also, I don't think you want to bind 'dialogopen' before you initialize the dialog.  Below should work just fine:

```
$("#acknowledged-dialog").dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui){
     setTimeout("$('#acknowledged-dialog').dialog('close')",3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: and no, unless you follow @toby and wrap the function, I have found i can not use 'this' in the above code for setTimeout.

Comment: Just wanted to note, in situations where that string eval won't work (like when I was making a Chrome extension), you can just turn the string into an anonymous function.

Comment: Note that if the user manually closes the dialog before the timeout, the timer in the above code will continue running and attempt to close the dialog a second time - this is ok unless the dialog is destroyed. But if the dialog is displayed a second time before the first timeout, the first timer will close the dialog early.

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle to mess around with this type of "auto close" function assignment. https://jsfiddle.net/cgjerdingen/20urmcg0/

Answer (score 9):

I wrote an [article](http://tobyho.com/2011/10/26/js-premature-invocation/) specifically for the problem you are experiencing. Please read that.

In short, you want to wrap `$("#mydialog").dialog('close')` with an inline function everywhere you want it executed as a result of a delay or a triggered event.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#mydialog").dialog('close')
}, 3000);
```

The dialog doesn't even show because you closed it as soon as you opened it in each case.

Comment: Fixed, due to DefyGravity pointing out you can't reference `this` inside the callback.

Comment: For future reference, you can use `this` stored in a variable. This works conveniently when you may have a dynamic dialog that doesn't necessarily have an id. Simply store `this` before the `setTimeout` inside the `open` callback and use the variable like a closure. This makes it more portable too. `open: function(event, ui){ var $this = $(this); setTimeout(function(){$this.dialog('close')}, 3000); }`