# auto close popup after second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using simple popup and I want to auto close popup after seconds. Please guide me how to do that

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".movenext").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).simplePopup({
            type: "html",
            htmlSelector: "#popupuser"},
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).simplePopup().close();
            }, 3000)
        );                                      
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954953/jquery-ui-dialog-auto-close-using-settimeout

Comment: You can pass `this` as a parameter: `setTimeout(function(self){ $(self).simplePopup().close();}, 3000, this)`

Comment: Hi @Werner, Thanks for your reply I am using [simple-popup-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-popup-modal) plugin and I am trying to auto close popup after 3 sec but I am unable to do this here is my [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/4qpg2qv1/) please have a look

Comment: @Yajuvendrapratapsingh  It seems that `simplePopup.js` does not have a build in *close*-function. At least I could not find a documentation about that... However. Here's a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3jp85djj/

Answer (score 2):

The callback given to setTimeout has no "this" value. Use a variable to store $(this) and use it in your setTimeout callback

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".movenext").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        element.simplePopup({
            type: "html",
            htmlSelector: "#popupuser"
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.simplePopup().close();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,, you are loosing the `this` scope inside `setTimeout` callback, see if that works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".movenext").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;
        $(this).simplePopup({
                type: "html",
                htmlSelector: "#popupuser"
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.simple-popup-content .close').click();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

EDIT:

I've updated your fiddle, see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/8vx0185d/1/

Comment: hey, @Yajuvendrapratapsingh I've updated your fiddle and answer. It works now but I dont think that custom jQuery library has `close()` function built in so I had to hack it a little :)